# How to load a Viewcontroller with Annotation information

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I'm building a application that allows people to post annotations on a map and you can click on the detail closure of the annotation and it loads a ViewController with the image and the subtitle information but when I try to load the image and subtitle in the viewDidLoad method of the detailVC it says it's nil

Here's my Annotation code:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

private struct Constants{
    static let identifier = "pin"
    static let LeftCalloutFrame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 59, height: 59)
    static let ShowPinSegueIdentifier = "showDetail"
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? PingAnnotation {
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(Constants.identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if view == nil {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: Constants.identifier)
            view?.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            view!.annotation = annotation
        }
        view!.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(frame: Constants.LeftCalloutFrame)
        view!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure) as UIView
        return view

    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let thumbnailImageView = view.leftCalloutAccessoryView as? UIImageView {
        if let pingAnnotation = view.annotation as? PingAnnotation{
            thumbnailImageView.image = pingAnnotation.image
        }
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.ShowPinSegueIdentifier, sender: view)
}


}
```

Annotation code:

```
class PingAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var image : UIImage?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?, image: UIImage?) {

    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.image = image
}
}
```

Detail VC Code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailPingVC: UIViewController {

var ping : PingAnnotation!


@IBOutlet var pingImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var pingDesc: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pingImage.image = ping.image //shows as nil when ran
    pingDesc.text = ping.subtitle //shows as nil when ran


}



    @IBAction func pingBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
}

    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

EDIT:

I tried using prepareForSegue but the values still come out nil

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destViewController: DetailPingVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailPingVC
    destViewController.pingImage.image = ping.image
    destViewController.pingDesc.text = ping.subtitle
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not implementing prepareForSegue:  In there you would set the ping property of DetailPingVC to the appropriate value.

Comment: Where would I implement prepareForSegue?

Comment: Have a look at the docs on UIViewController. There should be loads of examples online also.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Basically what I did was add a variable of type string and a variable of type UIImage to the DetailVC and then my prepareForSegue in my viewController looks as so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destViewController: DetailPingVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailPingVC

    destViewController.descText = postTextField.text!
    destViewController.detailImage = pickImage.image!
}
```

then in the viewDidLoad of the Detail VC you set the Outlets to the variables you set up earlier.